# How to add a custom mobile theme in an existing WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I've seen some WordPress themes that comes with a mobile theme, added inside the folder of the theme, and I am trying to create a custom mobile theme for my existing theme, and I've placed it inside my existing theme's folder named `mobile`. I'm using [Serban Ghita](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)'s mobile detect class, for detecting mobile devices.

I've already created the necessary files in the *mobile* folder (functions.php, style.css, index.php)

Here's what I have in the main theme's `functions.php` file:

```
require_once get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/Mobile_Detect.php'; // mobile detection

if(!function_exists('et_load_mobile')) {
    function et_load_mobile() {
        global $isMobile;
        $detector = new Mobile_Detect();
        $isMobile = $detector->isMobile() && ( ! $detector->isAndroidtablet() ) && ( ! $detector->isIpad() );
        $isMobile = apply_filters( 'et_is_mobile', $isMobile ? TRUE : FALSE );
        if ( $isMobile && ( ! isset( $_COOKIE[ 'mobile' ] ) || md5( 'disable' ) != $_COOKIE[ 'mobile' ] ) ) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

My question now is, how do I make WordPress to load the mobile theme in the `/mobile` folder, and display the corresponding template files.?
Also, I've registered a widget called mobile widget in the main theme, how do I call the widget in the mobile theme?

PS: I know there are plugins that can switch themes in the WP theme directory, but I really want to know how to do this without plugins, and also to understand the technology behind this kind of process.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If there's any link to a documentation somewhere, I'll appreciate that too.